# Error: On making Public Site to Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have Public Site and when I try to make the site Online I am facing the error as below.Can any one help me how can I sove it
[image]

Answer (score 0):

a) Have you renamed the site file? Modified in Visual Studio or Sharepoint Designer?

b) From the screenshot I see you have only Sharepoint Online license. Is it a new account? Is everything else correctly provisioned?

c) Have you customized your page in any way? It doesn't look like it, so can you try resetting the site to template and make it online again?

d) Have you ever been able to make it online?

e) Can you click on technical details and post the correlation id and the exact message here?